# Breakpoint not hit in managed code

Tags: debugging, c++-cli, unmanaged, managed

I have inherited an application consisting of a number of C#, C++/CLI and native C++ projects.

The app starts as an MFC application but loads the CLR during startup (via a process I'm not sure I fully understand yet<sup>†</sup>).

I've found that I can place breakpoints in native C++ code and that these work as expected. However, breakpoints in managed code do not work.

In C# I get:

> "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document".

In C++/CLI I Get:

> "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code is associated with this line. Possible causes include: preprocessor directives or compiler/linker optimizations".

I can even set two breakpoints in the same C++ file and have only one work, e.g.

```cpp
#pragma unmanaged

int CMyClass::UnmanagedFunc()
{
    // Breakpoint here works
    return 1
}

#pragma managed

int CMyClass::ManagedFunc()
{
    // Breakpoint here DOES NOT WORK!!
    return 2
}
```

The project settings for "Enable unmanaged code debugging" (within the managed library projects) has no effect on these breakpoints.
Is there some setting or config or *something* that I do do to allow me to interrupt and step through the managed parts of the code base?

<sup>†</sup>: The process loads `mscoree.dll`, and involves a complicated routine including `CLRCreateInstance`, `ICLRMetaHost`, `ICLRRuntimeHost`, `GetRuntime(..)`, `Start()` and `ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain(..)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since your main EXE is a native program, it is likely that the debugger starts up in unmanaged mode and will therefore not support setting breakpoints on managed code.  Project + Properties, Debugging, Debugger Type setting.  Change it from the default of Auto to Mixed or Managed Only.  Mixed debugging only works in 32-bit mode.

UPDATE: starting with VS2012 you also have to force the debugger to use the legacy managed code debugging engine, the one that still supports C++/CLI.  Tools > Options > Debugging > General > "Use managed compatibility mode" setting.

Comment: D'oh.  I knew it'd be something simple I was overlooking.  Changing this from "Auto" to "Mixed" has done the trick.....

Comment: Combining this answer with tools->Options->Debugging->General turn 'Use managed compatibility mode' solved the issue for me. Tnx!

Answer (score 2):

For me, the key was to change debugger type from Auto to Mixed, but for the startup application, not the library which contained the C++/CLI code (which is what I was trying to do).

Answer (score 0):

For the same error it works with me when I specified debugger type to:

"Native Only" or "Managed Only" **not** to Mixed or Auto!!!

Answer (score 0):

For me it was in project properties -> Linker -> Debugging -> Debuggable Assembly set to YES (/ASSEMBLYDEBUG)